# Spring cloud stream RabbitMQ randomly fails with queue NOT_FOUND error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have configured RabbitMQ cluster and I use Spring Cloud Stream over RabbitMQ with such a config:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;

public interface FileChangedSink {
    String INPUT = "fileChanged";

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel fileChanged();
}
```

And application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        fileChanged:
          destination: file.changed
          binder: stream_rabbit
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1

      binders:
        stream_rabbit:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: ${RABBITMQ_HOST}
                port: ${RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT_NUMBER}
                username: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
                password: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
                virtual-host: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST}
```

Versions:

```
Spring Boot Version: 1.5.10.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-stream: 1.3.2.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit: 1.3.3.RELEASE
```

Usually this config works ok, but recently I got such an exception with it:

```
2019-10-28T08:11:51.832Z 2019-10-28 08:11:51.831  WARN [search-service,,,] 1 --- [qW883QNAvQ-5986] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue: file.changed.anonymous.nL_BWxroRf65qW883QNAvQ
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z 2019-10-28 08:11:56.835 ERROR [search-service,,,] 1 --- [qW883QNAvQ-5986] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer received fatal=false exception on startup
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.QueuesNotAvailableException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it.
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:626)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1472)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[file.changed.anonymous.nL_BWxroRf65qW883QNAvQ]
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:718)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:594)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    ... 2 common frames omitted
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:992)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:50)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1279.invoke(Unknown Source)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:980)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy228.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:697)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    ... 3 common frames omitted
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'file.changed.anonymous.nL_BWxroRf65qW883QNAvQ' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    ... 11 common frames omitted
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'file.changed.anonymous.nL_BWxroRf65qW883QNAvQ' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.835Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.836Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.836Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.836Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.836Z    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572)
2019-10-28T08:11:56.836Z    ... 1 common frames omitted
2019-10-28T08:11:56.836Z 2019-10-28 08:11:56.835  INFO [search-service,,,] 1 --- [qW883QNAvQ-5986] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@2fe6f292: tags=[{}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://adminRGfa93@172.31.71.134:5672/,10419), conn: Proxy@2f143ea Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@1daf2e3e [delegate=amqp://adminRGfa93@172.31.71.134:5672/, localPort= 52338], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2019-10-28T08:11:56.848Z 2019-10-28 08:11:56.848  WARN [search-service,,,] 1 --- [qW883QNAvQ-5987] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue: file.changed.anonymous.nL_BWxroRf65qW883QNAvQ
2019-10-28T08:11:56.848Z 2019-10-28 08:11:56.848  WARN [search-service,,,] 1 --- [qW883QNAvQ-5987] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Queue declaration failed; retries left=3
2019-10-28T08:11:56.848Z org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[file.changed.anonymous.nL_BWxroRf65qW883QNAvQ]
```

**Note: This error is random and usually my config works ok.**

From the error I can understand that queue wasn't created before stream tries to connect to it.

*So my question is how it could happen and how I can prevent such a situation?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot 1.5.x is no longer supported; the last version 1.5.22 was released in August.

You need to set the queue argument `x-queue-master-locator` to `client-local` to ensure that an anonymous queue is created on the node that the application is connected to.

Starting with spring-amqp version 2.1 (used by Spring Boot 2.1 and binder 2.2), this is done automatically by the framework.

With earlier versions, you can set the master locator for your anonymous queues using a policy on the broker.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/245

**EDIT**

Screen shot of policy:

[image: Screen shot of policy]

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! Could you explain in more detail how I can set this argument on 1.5.10 version. I tried to add this to bean post processor: if (o instanceof CachingConnectionFactory) {
            ((CachingConnectionFactory) o).getRabbitConnectionFactory().getClientProperties()
                    .put("x-queue-master-locator", "client-local");
        }  but seems that it's not working. Thank you in advance!

Comment: As you can see I have only configuration file - no java config for the queues, so how I can put `x-queue-master-locator` to queue arguments?

Comment: You can't set a queue argument with stream 1.3.x; setting a connection client property is not the same; as I said you have to use a policy on the broker. Using the Admin UI go to `Admin | Policies` - see the screen shot in my answer.